# Check if date has exceeded 7 business days

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have an Excel sheet with some date columns.

One column is an "arrival" date.  The other is a "notice" date.

I need to create a formula (VLOOKUP or whatever) that can check if the notice date has exceeded 7 business days.

I created an extra column called "date check", which is where I'll create the formula.

As of right now, the sheet resembles this:

| reference | arrival date | notice date | date check |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test1 | 14-DEC-21 | 10-DEC-21 |  |
| test2 | 07-DEC-21 | 03-DEC-21 |  |
| test3 | 27-DEC-21 | 21-DEC-21 |  |
| test4 | 07-DEC-21 | 30-NOV-21 |  |

I need to write a formula within column D that will check the values in column C to see if they have exceeded 7 business days from the date in column C.

If I use today's date (16-DEC-21), then the above test case should should mark that test2 and test4 have exceeded 7 business days, as follows:

| reference | arrival date | notice date | date check |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test1 | 14-DEC-21 | 10-DEC-21 | N |
| test2 | 07-DEC-21 | 03-DEC-21 | Y |
| test3 | 27-DEC-21 | 21-DEC-21 | N |
| test4 | 07-DEC-21 | 30-NOV-21 | Y |

How can I make this work?

### Edit

I found this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(I:I, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$22)/((I$1:I$22<=TODAY()-7)*(I$1:I$22>0)), ROW(1:1))), "")
```

But I'm not sure how to incorporate it into my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use datedif() like this:

[image]

```
=IFERROR(IF(DATEDIF(C2,NOW(),"d")<7,"N","Y"),"N")
```

Or, correcting the other answer:

```
=IF(NETWORKDAYS(C2,NOW())>7,"Y","N")
```

Comment: I could not get your first solution to work, however when you corrected the other answer, I had success.  I have upvoted both answers, though I'm not sure which answer to accept.  I do want to thank both of you for helping me because I have been stuck on this for a couple of days.

Comment: @JohnBeasley not sure why the first one does not work for you, works for me as shown. Do accept an answer otherwise the Stack algorithm keeps bringing the question back.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula: `=IF(NETWORKDAYS(C4;B4)>7;"Y";"N")`

Comment: What does C4;B4 represent?

Comment: The question is not to compare the Arrival date to the Notice date...

Comment: @JohnBeasley B4 is arrival date c4 is notice date which is not the comparison you ask for.